# Non-nullish logic check for objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the correct/best way to refactor this logic, using nullish operator? -

```js
if (value !== undefined && value !== null && typeof value !== 'object') {
    // error, when not null/undefined, it must be an object
}
```

**UPDATE**

So far I've tried this one, which seems to be working, though looks a little odd:

```js
if (typeof (value ?? null) !== 'object') {
    // error...
}
```

Would that be a proper equivalent?

P.S. I'm writing this is TypeScript, so browsers compatibility doesn't concern me.

Comment: can you say more about what you want? Do you care about the then case or the else case in the check? Also, what's `??`, that doesn't seem to parse. If you want it to be an object, then `value && value instanceof Object` should work, no?

Comment: @NickParsons The question is really about the logic perfectly matching the original verification. I have been doing some testing locally, and it does seem to be the exact logical match for any `value` type. I'm just not sure if it is the best this way. I couldn't find any examples for proper reversing nullish logic.

Comment: This question would be better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). With that being said, the nullish coalescing operator isn't supported on Safari or Opera, so you may run into compatibility issues. Better might be to simply encapsulate the `value !== undefined && value !== null` checks into an `isDefined(value)` function for reusability until the operator has universal support. Reliable, maintainable code is far more important than shorter code! If you insist on using the operator, however, then `if(typeof(value ?? {}) !== 'object')` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @B.Fleming These days I'm writing everything in TypeScript, so browser compatibility doesn't concern me :) TypeScript supports null-ish operator and optional chaining syntax ever since v3.0.0

Comment: Ah, gotcha! If you're using TypeScript, then it's absolutely fine. I do caution you about relying on quirky behavior like `typeof(null)` resulting in a value of `"object"`, however, as that behavior could potentially change in the future and it's not really compatible with a similar condition of e.g. `typeof(value ?? null) !== 'string'`. Consider doing `typeof(value ?? {}) !== 'object'` instead to make your intentions clear and to avoid possible future compatibility issues.

Comment: @B.Fleming Would you, please, detail that in a proper answer?

Comment: @vitaly-t "If you do not even know what that is, probably better leaving it :)" Sorry for trying to help, dude. I'll try to avoid it going forward ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Although your existing implementation example will work, JavaScript's `typeof` function has a longstanding history of causing confusion in the case of `typeof(null)` returning `'object'`. One of your most important considerations in refactoring code will always be the maintainability of your code, and any likely source of confusion is likely to reduce maintainability.

If someone were to look at this code right now, particularly any developer who is inexperienced with JavaScript or has never run into the `typeof(null)` quirk, they would assume that your code is looking for all non-object types, *including* the values of `null` and `undefined` rather than *excluding* them.

Additionally, although current JavaScript standards are unlikely to change the behavior of `typeof(null)` to avoid breaking existing code, there's no absolute guarantee that this behavior will never change. There's especially no guarantee that TypeScript itself won't change this behavior to be more intuitive and transcompile down to a different JavaScript equivalent.

You're far better off avoiding confusion in your code as well as potentially future compatibility breaking updates if you modify the default fallback value for your nullish coalescing operation. Specifically, default to `{}` which is always guaranteed to be interpreted as an object and will be far less likely to be subject to breaking changes in either JavaScript or TypeScript:

```js
if (typeof (value ?? {}) !== 'object') {
    // error...
}
```

Comment: I did try with an object it too, but my way of thinking was that `null` is cheaper, without creating a new object :) Also, I'm a bit skeptical that `typeof(null)` will ever change the result :)

Comment: Regarding cheapness, the impact of creating a new object on the stack that is then freed immediately after moving up from the current scope is negligible and not really worth considering. If you're really concerned about it, however, creating a global constant would allow a single allocation and effectively remove the already negligible performance impact. Regarding `typeof(null)` changing, I agree that it's unlikely. I never trust "unlikely" when it comes to code maintainability, however, as "unlikely" has caused me many, many headaches already. Better safe than sorry!

Comment: Probably the cheapest and most reliable one is `typeof(value ?? Object.prototype)`, but it is too verbose, and therefore not favorable :)